# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject omit bracket

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
string myString ="{\"val\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"lua\"}}";
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myString);
```

so

```
 json ={{
"attributes": {
"id": 1,
"name": "lua"}
}}
```

something like this.
but i want to make json just like this:

```
[{
"attributes": {
"id": 1,
"name": "lua"}
}]
```

How can i do that in C# using Json.Convert or another way?

Comment: You cannot do that. JSON string is defined within a curly braces. However you can have array structure like {"value":[{
"attributes": {
"id": 1,
"name": "lua"}
}] }

Comment: Yes,but i can't use like {[{ "attributes": { "id": 1, "name": "lua"} }] } , i need to omit first and last curly bracket. thanks @DanHunex

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you want to make the JSON string like  `[{"attributes": {"id": 1,"name": "lua"}}]`, can't you just change `myString` to be what you want?